# How to overwrite base controller beforeAction method

Tags: plugin-development

How do you override the beforeAction method of Craft's base controller? I'm disabling CSRF for a specific route.

```
public function beforeAction($action): bool
{
    $requestOrigin = \Craft::$app->getRequest()->headers->get('Origin');
    $origin = getenv('ENVIRONMENT') === 'dev' ? getenv('ORIGIN_DEV') :getenv('ORIGIN_PRODUCTION');

    / Disable CSRF validation for valid origins
    if ($requestOrigin === $origin) {
      $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }

    if (!parent::beforeAction($action)) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I know that there have been similar questions asked before on overriding plugin methods and there's also the blueprint inside the controller itself. Just struggling to understand how to override the `craft\web\Controller`'s method for this

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to create a custom controller in a module that extends the cart controller.
This gives the functionality to overwrite the `beforeAction` method, while keeping all other functionality.

As an example:

```
<?php

namespace modules\controllers;

use craft\commerce\controllers\CartController;

class FooController extends CartController
{
    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        // Your overwritten logic here
        $something = 'test';

        return $something;
    }
}
```

Instead of posting to `commerce/cart/update-cart` you would then (in the example above) post to  `my-module/foo/update-cart`. There is some useful documentation in the Craft docs on [building a custom module](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/module-guide.html) and how to create customer controllers and actions.

[Answered by Nathaniel Hammond Pixel & Tonic]